# Multi-stage Dockerfile

Tags: docker, android-sdk-tools, docker-image, docker-multi-stage-build

I found a dockerfile for android sdk

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk wget unzip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux

RUN mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME} && \
    cd ${ANDROID_HOME} && \
    wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip -O android_tools.zip && \
    unzip android_tools.zip && \
    rm android_tools.zip

ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

I connect to docker image. Apk building works fine.

But my project requires different dependencies. Another dockerfile content is below:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It work for pyhton app.

But, how can I combine these files?

Below settings doesn't work:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk wget unzip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux

RUN mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME} && \
    cd ${ANDROID_HOME} && \
    wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip -O android_tools.zip && \
    unzip android_tools.zip && \
    rm android_tools.zip

ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I connect docker image. Apk build is failed. The error is here:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in
>   your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

When using docker multi-stage build, every stage starts with `FROM` and it doesn't accumulate the files from previous stages (and neither environment variables), you have to manually copy the files you want. For example in the next Dockerfile the, the built image will be the same as `openjdk:8` and won't have neither your app or python.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM openjdk:8
```

To copy files from previous stage you need to mention which files and from which stage to copy:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine AS python

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=python /app .
```

Multi-stage build used mostly if you need something like a compiler only for the build process and not for the final image. it allows you to use image with the dependencies you need in the build and then leave them behind and use only the final product and the dependencies needed for runtime.

For your Dockerfile, if you need both python and java multi-stage build won't help, you should look for base image that contains both, or start with one image (let's say java) and then manually install the other (python).

Comment: I need a final image that contains android-sdk and  python development environment. Current flow is python->output->copy output to second layer->java(without ruby)->final image for my multi-stage settings now. Am I right?

Comment: I didn't understand you. the flow you presented isn't the same as your Dockerfile above. If you need anrdoid sdk +python, use the first Dockerfile and add to it install of python using `apt-get`

Comment: Yes, I need python+android sdk.